# tridium niagara 4 dropdown in baja.jar

Tags: java, niagara-4

There is one software Tridium Niagara 4, which is private not opensource. This software put everything secure. No documentation for development troubleshooting and the documents are also clumsy, they are not in simple words.

For non programmers it is miry pit. I have been given the task for GPIO port on one device. We have our own API in .cpp , which is tested and is working.

Backend is working fine with all native callbacks but now we need to create GUI for GPIO. And we need combobox instead of textblock so we can restrict user from entering random values.

We tried with following command but not working any idea?

```
@NiagaraType
@NiagaraProperty (
  name = "direction",
  type = "bajaui:BListDropdown",
  defaultValue = "in"
)
```

This software provides info from Tridium(name of the company) only, and they call the developers who use their software - "Niagara Developer". I hope they will give suggestions or answer on stack overflow sites.

Comment: Best luck with your request, but honestly: not much chance of hearing from that company here. Some companies use SO and watch out for questions around their products, so you get answers quickly. But such companies are "developer friendly" anyway. They have great documentation, and a great support forum on their web sites. So a company that does none of that ... they will probably not read here (if at all, you could see if other users answered similar questions before, and see if you can drop them a comment).

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/niagaraaxcommun/code/HEAD/tree/N4/axCommunity-wb/src/org/axcommunity/niagara/widgets/BDropDownList.java#l57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a UI element as a Niagara property like this. In your case, the property probably needs to be a class that you develop which extends BFrozenEnum - in other words, the property is really the data model if you want to think of it in terms of the MVC programming paradigm. The dropdown you describe would instead be a widget inside a Px file, workbench view or something similar which would render the enumerated value of your BFrozenEnum.

In terms of the wider scope of your question, there is a Tridium business model whereby anyone who wants to develop using Niagara should really be thinking about certification. Niagara isn't simply just Java + UI: it is a complete framework built on top of the bare bones language and (I speak from personal experience) you need to have a thorough grounding & training in it before you can make any progress. That developer training, for instance, would explain how you implement a BListDropDown and similar widgets to render your data, and would take you on a tour of the developer documentation.

That same business model I just described also provides developers with technical support (not about Java, but about how you program and extend the framework), but the support has to be paid for. As another response has already said, you can of course expect general Java questions to be answered in StackOverflow, but the only answers to framework-specific questions posted here will come from interested Niagara developers like myself, not from the Tridium corporation itself.

Sorry that I can't be of more assistance.